# Possible bug in VonMisesDistribution?

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

**Bug introduced in 10.2 or earlier and fixed in 10.3**

---

Observe:

```
FullSimplify[PDF[VonMisesDistribution[μ, 0], x], -π + μ <= x <= π + μ] == 
 FullSimplify[PDF[UniformDistribution[{μ - π, μ + π}], x], -π + μ <= x <= π + μ]

(* True *)

SeedRandom[1]
RandomVariate@UniformDistribution[{0 - π, 0 + π}]
RandomVariate@VonMisesDistribution[0, 0]
```

> 1.99422
>
> CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 19;
>   proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity
>   encountered. >>

at which point it just hangs, never completing.

This appears to be for any mean with concentration 0.

Comment: Your first line can be written more simply as `Simplify[PDF[VonMisesDistribution[\[Mu], 0], x] == PDF[UniformDistribution[{\[Mu] - \[Pi], \[Mu] + \[Pi]}], x], -\[Pi] + \[Mu] <= x <= \[Pi] + \[Mu]]`

Comment: If memory serves, the method used internally is the [rejection method of Best and Fisher](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2346732); if you'll look through their algorithm, they implicitly make the assumption that $\kappa$ is positive. So, their algorithm will not work in your case, and there should have been a separate internal handler for $\kappa=0$.

Comment: This is indeed a bug. We're looking into it.

Answer (score 7):

To me this looks like a bug. A possible workaround is to use [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html?q=ProbabilityDistribution) together with the `PDF` of the `VonMisesDistribution`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomVariate@ProbabilityDistribution[PDF[VonMisesDistribution[0, 0], x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

$\ $ `1.99422`

This bug is caused by the evaluation of

```
Statistics`NormalDistributionsDump`compiledvonmisesrandom[0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: As noted in WRI comment, it is indeed a bug.

Comment: Oops - forgot to upvote you, +1

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comment by WRI staff, this is indeed a bug in the interplay between `RandomVariate` and the distribution at hand.

The obvious workaround for now is to use

```
UniformDistribution[{μ - Pi, μ + Pi}]
```

for zero-concentration cases.

Comment: If I got it correct `RandomVariate@VonMisesDistribution[0, 0]` will call ``Statistics`NormalDistributionsDump`compiledvonmisesrandom[0, 0, 1]`` and if you have a look into that, you'll find things like `(2*kappa)^(-1)`.

Comment: @Karsten7.: yep - I titled it with the dist and not RandomVariate since it seems to me it's the specific "hooks" for the dist that have boo-boos... I just used Block in the piece of code affected for me and gave a downvalue for VMD with zero concentration that evaluates to the uniform.

Comment: @Karsten, then yes, they are indeed using Best-Fisher. As noted, it can't handle $\kappa=0$.